# Is it feasible to implemenent Linux concurrency primitives that give better isolation than threads but comparable performance?

Tags: linux, multithreading, concurrency, ipc

Consider a following application: a web search server that upon start creates a large in-memory index of web pages based on data read from disk. Once initialized, in-memory index can not be modified and multiple threads are started to serve user queries. Assume the server is compiled to native code and uses OS threads.

Now, threading model gives no isolation between threads. A buggy thread or any non thread safe code, can corrupt the index or corrupt memory that was allocated by and logically belongs to some other thread. Such problems are difficult to detect and debug.

Theoretically, Linux allows to enforce a better isolation. Once index is initialized, memory it occupies can be marked read only. Threads can be replaced with processes that share the index (shared memory) but other than that have separate heaps and can not corrupt each other. Illegal operation are automatically detected by hardware and the operating system. No mutexes or other synchronization primitives are needed. Memory related data races are completely eliminated.

Is such model feasible in practice? Are you aware of any real life application that do such things? Or maybe there are some fundamental difficulties that make such model impractical? Do you think such approach would introduce a performance overhead compared to traditional threads? Theoretically, memory that is used is the same, but are there some implementation-related issues that would make things slower?

Comment: There certainly are application that use mmap to mark various memory spaces as read-only.  However, this typically is for performance reasons and not for protection against buggy code.

Comment: Although I certainly don't want to start a religious war but switching to using a language (such as Java) which supports truly immutable types would solve a lot of the problems with "buggy threads" that "corrupt memory".

Comment: Memory corruption in multi-threading programs happens not only when thread writes to a random location in memory (such errors are relatively easy to avoid and detect) but also when thread obtains a valid reference to an object that is not thread safe and that is used by some other thread. Such errors are much more difficult to prevent and detect and can happen in any multi-threading program, no matter what language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution is to not use threads at all.  Use separate processes.  Since each process has much in common with code and readonly structures, making the readonly data shared is trivial:  format it as needed for in-memory use within a file and map the file to memory.

Using this scheme, only the variable per-process data would be independent.  The code would be shared and statically initialized data would be shared until written.  If a process croaks, there is zero impact on other processes.  No concurrency issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mprotect()` to make your index read-only.  On a 64-bit system you can map the local memory for each thread at a random address (see [this Wikipedia article on address space randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)) which makes the odds of memory corruption from one thread touching another astronomically small (and of course any corruption that misses mapped memory altogether will cause a segfault).  Obviously you'll need to have different heaps for each thread.

Comment: Can threads have different heaps, or does different heap distinguish threads from processes?

Comment: The heap is just where `malloc` gets its memory.  To give different threads different heaps just requires each thread draw from a different pool (using thread-specific data).  You just need the right malloc library with the right options.

Comment: The problem is that heap randomization idea would prevent only one class of bugs - corruption of memory due to writes to random locations. As I wrote in other comment such bugs are relatively easier to prevent and detect. The bigger problem are data races that full isolation would completely eliminate. Say one thread calls a function that returns a pointer to a non thread safe static object. If other thread calls the same function, you have a data race, and it does not help that the returned pointer is randomized. The pointer wasn't guessed it was obtained via a valid call.

Comment: @JanWrobel: I didn't understand from your question that you wanted to avoid having to write thread-safe code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find [memcached](http://memcached.org/) interesting. Also, you can create a shared memory and open it as read-only and then create your threads. This should not cause much performance degradation.